# Install wifi on minimum OS

Tags: wifi, pi-3

I've setup a RaspberryPi 3 using a minimum OS like [raspberrypi-ua-netinst](https://github.com/FooDeas/raspberrypi-ua-netinst) (preset:server) but also would like to enjoy the onboard wifi-adapter. Unfortunately I can't enter the credentials in the installer-config.txt but would like to add them later. The point is, that the folder:

```
/etc/wpa_supplicant/
```

and the config *wpa_supplicant.conf* doesn't exist in any case.

Does anybody know how to set up wifi, to get wifi working using the common  way via the config to enter the credentials?

Comment: This is more like a comment, I don't have enough reputation to add a comment so forgive me. if you have connmanctl (it's a network manager for embedded devices so it's a high probability you have it) installed on you pi, you can check the following tutorial to connect to a wifi access point. [Connman:Enabling_and_disabling_wifi](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Connman#Enabling_and_disabling_wifi)

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you have wpa_supplicant installed yet. Is it included in the minimal image? Try to update your repositories and install wpa_supplicant:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install wpasupplicant
```

Next, edit the `wpa_supplicant` file which should now be present:

```
sudo nano /etc/wpa_supplicant/wpa_supplicant.conf
```

Add your network details at the end of that file:

```
network={
    ssid="yourwifiname"
    psk="yourwifipass"
}
```

Save the file using `CTRL+x` (confirm with y) and restart the wpa interface:

```
sudo wpa_cli reconfigure
```

Then check if you are connected to your network:

```
ifconfig wlan0
```

Answer (score 0):

It's possible to specify the credentials since raspberrypi-ua-netinst v1.2.1.
Just add this to an `installer-config.txt` on the SD card:

```
ifname=wlan0
wlan_ssid=changeme
wlan_psk=changeme
```

All that information is in the `README.md` of the repository and shown on GitHub.

Otherwise, you can create the directory and the file by yourself.